# JavaScript to change page color based on day of week and time frame schedule

Tags: javascript, html, date, responsive, schedule

I'm working on building a page to be a simple to look at page that tells the user if a shop is open or closed. I'm trying to have it display a green background and "yes, open" or a red background with "no, closed". The schedule varies every day of the week and some days the shop closes midday and reopens later. I'm having trouble getting the background and text to correctly change according to the time.

I tried implementing solutions from [this user's similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117192/javascript-if-for-various-days-and-hours), but I couldn't quite get them to work. I tried both the solution from 'Arnav Aggarwal' as well as the one below it from 'Darkisa'. Arnav's uses a flag set false and if statements.

When using the flag it seems to not care about the hours, only the day, put perhaps I am simply doing it wrong. Below is a code snippet, but I also have the code set up on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/bcr27/pen/wvKoPWQ)

```js
let t = document.getElementById("Status");
t.innerHTML = "No";
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";

var q = new Date();
var hour = q.getHours();
var day = q.getDay();

function isBetween(testNumber, lowerLimit, upperLimit) {
  return testNumber >= lowerLimit || testNumber <= upperLimit;
}

var flag = false;

if (day === 2 && (isBetween(hour, 0, 5) || isBetween(hour, 6, 7))) {
  flag = true;
}

if (flag) {
  let t = document.getElementById("Status");
  t.innerHTML = "Yes";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
#status {width: 3em}
```

```html
<div id="Status"></div>
```

For me, Arnav's code seems more my speed as it is clearer what is happening and I'm not super familiar with loops and arrays like Darkisa's reply.

I additionally tried making a series of if else statements, but they do not work unless the day is [6], or Saturday.

[Code using Arnav's Flag solution](https://codepen.io/bcr27/pen/wvKoPWQ)

[Code using stacked If Else](https://codepen.io/bcr27/pen/MWabGPQ)

Comment: `testNumber >= lowerLimit || testNumber <= upperLimit` should use `&&` not `||`, otherwise it will return true for every non–NaN number value of *testNumber* where `lowerLimit <= upperLimit`. But why are you doing this on the client? Do it on the server, where you know the clock is accurate.

Comment: @RobG I think you cracked it for me! Using `testNumber >= lowerLimit && testNumber <= upperLimit` it works. I also changed the `<=` to `<` so it does not include the entire hour. But this now has me needing to make another change since some of the times land on half hour intervals and this code only calls for full hours. I am doing this on a client because I do not have a server for it, I guess. I'm not familiar with those things, unfortunately, but am willing to learn! Ultimately I want to move this onto a RaspberryPi to host it.